# How to set a margin gap different than the space between buttons?

Tags: java, swing

I have a button panel and I want a space of 25px between the buttons and a right margin of 5px and a left margin of 5px (the button at the right would be at 5 pixels of the window border).

Flow layout set a gap of the same size everywhere. Gridlayout permit to do that, but then all the buttons have the same size and it is no that I want. The only solution I found is to set Flow layout with hgap=0. then I had an emptyMargin and I but a rigid area before each button, but I think this solution is a bad practice.

What is the best solution to do that ?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class FlowLayoutDemo extends JFrame{
    FlowLayout experimentLayout = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 25, 0);

    public FlowLayoutDemo(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    public void addComponentsToPane(final Container pane) {
        final JPanel compsToExperiment = new JPanel();
        compsToExperiment.setLayout(experimentLayout);
        experimentLayout.setAlignment(FlowLayout.TRAILING);
        compsToExperiment.add(new JButton("Button 1"));
        compsToExperiment.add(new JButton("Button 2"));
        compsToExperiment.add(new JButton("Button 3"));
        compsToExperiment.add(new JButton("Long-Named Button 4"));
        compsToExperiment.add(new JButton("5"));
        pane.add(compsToExperiment, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        FlowLayoutDemo frame = new FlowLayoutDemo("FlowLayoutDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.addComponentsToPane(frame.getContentPane());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using a `GridBagLayout` instead, it provides a greater amount of control and customisation.

[image: Buttons]

See [How to use `GridBagLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more details.

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 25);
            gbc.fill = gbc.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc.weightx = 1;

            add(new JButton("Button 1"), gbc);
            gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 0, 5, 25);
            add(new JButton("Button 2"), gbc);
            add(new JButton("Button 3"), gbc);
            add(new JButton("Long-Named Button 4"), gbc);
            gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 0, 5, 5);
            add(new JButton("5"), gbc);
        }

    }

}
```

Note, the example forces the buttons too occupy ALL of the available space.  If this doesn't meet your needs in particular, try playing around with the `fill` and `weightx` values

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to use the `GridBagLayout` as it shown in example of MadProgrammer. But it also possible using `FlowLayout`. Here is the example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class FlowLayoutDemo extends JFrame {
    FlowLayout experimentLayout = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 5, 0);

    public FlowLayoutDemo(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    public void addComponentsToPane(final Container pane) {
        final JPanel compsToExperiment = new JPanel();
        compsToExperiment.setLayout(experimentLayout);
        experimentLayout.setAlignment(FlowLayout.TRAILING);
        compsToExperiment.add(new JButton("Button 1"));
        compsToExperiment.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(20));
        compsToExperiment.add(new JButton("Button 2"));
        compsToExperiment.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(20));
        compsToExperiment.add(new JButton("Button 3"));
        compsToExperiment.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(20));
        compsToExperiment.add(new JButton("Long-Named Button 4"));
        compsToExperiment.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(20));
        compsToExperiment.add(new JButton("5"));
        pane.add(compsToExperiment, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        FlowLayoutDemo frame = new FlowLayoutDemo("FlowLayoutDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.addComponentsToPane(frame.getContentPane());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get tricky so you don't need to play with all the constraints of GridBagLayout or add filler components you could do:

```
JPanel compsToExperiment = new JPanel(experimentLayout);
compsToExperiment.setBorder( new EmptyBorder(0, -20, 0, -20) );
```

This effectively decrease the space by 20 pixels around the left/right edges of the panel.

Also, just wanted to point out that you have:

```
FlowLayout experimentLayout = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 25, 0);

...

experimentLayout.setAlignment(FlowLayout.TRAILING);
```

You set the layout to left aligned and then change it to trailing. This is a little confusing. You can just set it to trailing when you create the layout:

```
FlowLayout experimentLayout = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.TRAILING, 25, 0);
```